# Организация логики в yii2

Tags: yii2

Я всегда думал, что вся бизнес логика должна происходить в модулях, а не в контроллере, но получается что я не могу сделать класс без взаимодействия с базой данных в gii. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в YII2 я обработчик я должен писать в контролере без создания отдельного класса.

Comment: не правильно понимаете)) если вы хотите следовать правилу DDD в yii2 то придётся очень сильно постараться. Придётся написать некоторые костыли и велосипеды и поискать DDD шаблоны для Yii2  на github - но тем не менее, правильно делать именно бизнес логику независимо от правил работы yii2.  На elisdn есть цикл статей на эту тему. вот пара из них: https://elisdn.ru/blog/104/domain-entities-modelling и https://elisdn.ru/blog/109/domain-entities-active-record посмотрите полистайте. Плюс на форуме yii2 https://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewforum.php?f=34  есть что-то.

Comment: Если не следовать DDD - то будете по классике - логику выносить в модель))

Comment: Логику не обязательно выносить в модель. Можно добавить менеджеры, сервисы и обработчики, которые будут вызываться в контроллерах и дергать модели и т.д.